# Windows Firewall problem GP0 SP3

Tags: security, windows-xp

I have recently rolled XP service pack 3 out on the estate, and for some reason it is enabling the windows firewall. I have a group policy that disables the windows firewall but SP3 is turning it on.
Is there any way in GPO that I can turn this off, or is there a setting in SP3 that can be done globally.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

How are you turning it off via GPO? My suggestion is to use GPO to set the Windows Firewall service to disabled.

Comment: The GPO is set to disable, but fpr some wired reason SP XP3 is turning it back on.

Comment: Have you verified that the GPO is being applied to the computers in question?

Comment: The GPO is being applied all of the machines